# Add a pin on pin interest from rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth, pinterest

I was working on social integration for my Application.

I can post an Item on Facebook by accessing facebook API by `fb_graph gem`.

Similarly I wanted to know that how can I Add/Create pin from rails like we are doing for facebook instead of using "Pin it" button.

Because "Pin it" button works as a js plugin. I want to post a image(pin) on 'Pin Interest' in background.

Just FYI we are authenticating facebook, pin interest etc. by `omniauth gems`.

Thanks